# React Native Tab Navigator: How to let icon overflow tabbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to let the logo center in the tarbar, and that is overflow tabbar on the top. How to do it ? .......
...................................................................................................................................................

```
import React from 'react';
import TabNavigator from 'react-native-tab-navigator';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        selectedTab:'首页',
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TabNavigator tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle} tabBarShadowStyle={styles.tabBarShadowStyle}>
          <TabNavigator.Item
            selected={this.state.selectedTab === '首页'}
            title="首页"
            selectedTitleStyle={styles.selectedTitleStyle}
            renderIcon={() => <Image style={styles.tabBarIcon} source={require('../../res/images/icons/home.png')}/>}
            renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image style={[styles.tabBarSelectedIcon ]} source={require('../../res/images/icons/home.png')}/>}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: '首页' })} >
            <Text>首页</Text>
          </TabNavigator.Item>
          <TabNavigator.Item
            selected={this.state.selectedTab === '产品'}
            title="产品"
            selectedTitleStyle={styles.selectedTitleStyle}
            renderIcon={() => <Image style={styles.tabBarIcon} source={require('../../res/images/icons/product.png')}/>}
            renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image style={[styles.tabBarSelectedIcon ]} source={require('../../res/images/icons/product.png')}/>}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: '产品' })} >
            <Text>产品</Text>
          </TabNavigator.Item>
          <TabNavigator.Item
            renderIcon={() => <Image style={styles.logoIcon} source={require('../../res/images/icons/logo_tab.png')}/>} >
          </TabNavigator.Item>
          <TabNavigator.Item
            selected={this.state.selectedTab === '活动'}
            title="活动"
            selectedTitleStyle={styles.selectedTitleStyle}
            renderIcon={() => <Image style={styles.tabBarIcon} source={require('../../res/images/icons/activity.png')}/>}
            renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image style={[styles.tabBarSelectedIcon ]} source={require('../../res/images/icons/activity.png')}/>}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: '活动' })} >
            <Text>活动</Text>
          </TabNavigator.Item>
          <TabNavigator.Item
            selected={this.state.selectedTab === '我的'}
            title="我的"
            selectedTitleStyle={styles.selectedTitleStyle}
            renderIcon={() => <Image style={styles.tabBarIcon} source={require('../../res/images/icons/profile.png')}/>}
            renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image style={[styles.tabBarSelectedIcon ]} source={require('../../res/images/icons/profile.png')}/>}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: '我的' })} >
            <Text>我的</Text>
          </TabNavigator.Item>
        </TabNavigator>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  tabBarStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    overflow: 'visible',
  },
  tabBarShadowStyle: {
    height: 0,
  },
  selectedTitleStyle: {
    color: '#b42325',
  },
  logoIcon: {
    zIndex: 9999,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -50,
    left: -25,
    width: 60, height: 60,
  },
  tabBarIcon: {
    width: 26, height: 26,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    tintColor: '#5f5f5f',
  },
  tabBarSelectedIcon: {
    width: 26, height: 26,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    tintColor: '#b42325',
  }
});

export default App;
```

Current like this 
[image]

And I want to like this..
[image]

Comment: Can you give a z-index or overflow: visible to tabbar?

Comment: no. This is a try, but nothing happen.

Comment: add a specific style to item which you want to overlay top. In the style add position absolute and zIndex 1

Comment: @Leen have you solved this? Thanks

Comment: any luck on this problem ?

Comment: I have run into the same issue. The icon overlaps correctly on iOS but not on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom navigator to customize your tab view could to the trick, but it will include more effort.
Here is the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/custom

And here is a small example https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/CustomTabs.js